# How to add audio which will play Continue through out the site with out Stoping

Tags: playback, audio, continue

Is there any possibility to add audio files on website which will play continue through out the website even when the user navigate between pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could open a new separate window for audio player, or use iframe?

http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/keepplaying.html